# TURN OFF: "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

**How do I turn off this constraint conflict logging?**

Eventually, I will get back to fixing the constraints in my project.  In the meantime, I am unable to read my console due to all the crap that's being spammed.

I'm talking about:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029b120 UIView:0x7fc03fd87c90.centerY == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc03fd852a0.centerY   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-02-06 16:39:34.094262-0600 Project[12092:1055478] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029b940 UIView:0x7fc03fd8af60.width == 1   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029bad0 UIView:0x7fc03fd8b140.width == 1   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00009e870 UITextField:0x7fc040949600.width == 99   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029bd00 H:|-(114.5)-[UIView:0x7fc03fd8b140]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc03fd8ad80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029bdf0 H:[UIView:0x7fc03fd8b140]-(7.5)-[UITextField:0x7fc040949600]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029be90 H:[UITextField:0x7fc040949600]-(6.5)-[UIView:0x7fc03fd8af60]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029bee0 H:[UIView:0x7fc03fd8af60]-(113.5)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc03fd8ad80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029c0c0 H:[UIView:0x7fc03fd8ad80]-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc03fd891d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00029c110 UIView:0x7fc03fd8ad80.centerX == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc03fd891d0.centerX   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028c530 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc03fd891d0.width == 414   (active)>"
)
```

My MacPro on my desk doesn't have this problem but my laptop does.  There must be a way to make it stop.  I promise someday I will fix those constraints.  Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tried in a while, but this used to work:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey:"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
```